# Lagrangian formulation of conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

In some articles that I read, I often encountered the same formulation for one-dimensional conservation laws of the form $$u_t+(F(u)u)_x=0$$ where $F(u)$ may also depend on $u_x$, etc., and $u(t=0,x)=u_0(x)$ is given. The unknown function is $u : \mathbb{R}_t \times \mathbb{R}_x \to \mathbb
R$.

Let $X(t, \cdot) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $X_t=F(t,u(t,X(t,x)))$, $X(0,x)=x$, which is the *Lagrangian map* of the field $F$, then solutions of the form $$u(t,X(t,x))=\frac{1}{X_x(t,x)}u_0(x)$$ may be sought.

**Question:** Is there an explanation of the last expression? Is it natural?

Because usually we want to write $u(t,x)=u_0(X(t,x))$ and then look for the equation satisfied by $X$. Here I find the expression for $u$ somehow unnatural and unexpected.  The previous equations and notations arise in the article (1), §3.1.1 (p. 12 of the arXiv preprint).

---

(1) P. Germain, B. Harrop-Griffiths, J.L. Marzuola, "Existence and uniqueness of solutions for a quasilinear KdV equation with degenerate dispersion", *Comm. Pure Appl. Math.*, 2019. [doi:10.1002/cpa.21828](https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.21828) [arXiv:1801.00420v1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00420.pdf)

Comment: $u$ is defined as the solution to the equation writen, one can take $F(u)=u^2$ for example. $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is defined in my message as the solution to the equation $\partial _t X = F(u(t,X))$.

Comment: @Harry49 you can check this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00420.pdf  section 1.7 (on page 5) and more importantly section 3.1.1 on page 12. If someone can explain why such introduction of $X$ and why the formula $u(t,X(t,X(t,x))=u_0(x)/X_x(t,x)$ instead of $u(t,x)=u_0(X(t,x))$, thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess the error is in $u_t=(bu)_x$, it should be $u_t=(bu)_X$ since it is differentiation with respect to the second variable. This makes the computation correct then.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{\text d}{\text dt}(X_xu)$ would be zero, then we would have $X_xu=u_0(x)$. With the present notations, we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text d}{\text dt}(X_x u) &= X_{xt}u+X_x(u_t+u_XX_t) \\
&= b_xu+X_x(−(bu)_x+u_Xb)\\
&=X_x(1−X_x)(bu)_X
\end{aligned}
$$
which is nonzero in general.
However, considering that $(bu)_x$ represents differentiation w.r.t. the second variable of $[bu](t,X(t,x))$, then we may rewrite the conservation law as
$
u_t + (bu)_X = 0
$.
Doing so, $\frac{\text d}{\text dt}(X_xu)$ vanishes, and the proposed solution is obtained.

Comment: Well, i'm ok with that but this does not answer the question ...